# Select format mysql to highchart in php

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

can you help me please to select database to get something like:

```
"data": [
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 01), 75],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 02), 70],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 02), 80],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 02), 45],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 03), 65],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 03), 40],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 11, 05), 75]
      ]
```

My current select looks as follow:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(due_date, start_date)as diff, due_date from project WHERE project_id =77' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $diff .= "" . $row["diff"]. ",";
        $due_date .= "" . $row["due_date"]. ",";
```

So the resuls looks like this:

```
2,2,3,4,5,6
2018-01-26,2018-01-26,2018-01-27,2018-01-29,2018-01-29,2018-02-01
```

Is there any possible to get the results like:

```
        [Date.UTC(2018, 01, 26), 2],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 01, 26), 2],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 01, 27), 3],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 01, 29), 4],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 01, 29), 5],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 02, 01), 6]
```

Os something to put in these above format to work in highchart.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to produce `[Date.UTC(2018, 02, 01), 6]` without constructing it yourself, which is bad practice. Instead, just create the Date.UTC return value (milliseconds timestamp) it will work just fine.

Then you use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode it for your js.

Try this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$result = [
    ['diff' => '1', 'due_date' => '2018-02-01'],    
    ['diff' => '2', 'due_date' => '2018-02-02'],    
    ['diff' => '3', 'due_date' => '2018-02-03']   
];

$return = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $return[] = [strtotime($row["due_date"]) * 1000, (int) $row["diff"]];
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

https://3v4l.org/8gMmp

**Result:**

```
[
    [
        1517439600000,
        1
    ],
    [
        1517526000000,
        2
    ],
    [
        1517612400000,
        3
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes but how to corelate this with my MYSQL select?

Comment: @Maciej You only need change `foreach ($result as $row) {` to `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` look at the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct select:

```
SELECT group_concat(CONCAT('[Date.UTC(', DATE_FORMAT
(due_date,'%Y,%m,%d')), '), ',DATEDIFF(due_date, start_date), ']') 
as diff from project_has_tasks WHERE project_id =$sum8
```